# How to set scroll focus?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's suppose I have an HTML like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="large-content">
      large content
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
#container {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#large-content {
  height: 500px;
}
```

How can I allow the user to scroll the container by pressing the arrow keys after he clicks on the `#header`?

I already tried `.click()` and `.focus()` on the `#container` without success. I can't find how Chrome manages the scroll focus.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does @David answer answers your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `tabindex` attribute to the `#container` element, then use `.focus()`:

```js
var headerEl = document.querySelector('#header'),
    scrollEl = document.querySelector('#container');
    
 headerEl.addEventListener('click', function () {
  scrollEl.focus();
 });
```

```css
#container {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#large-content {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div id="container" tabindex="0">
    <div id="large-content">
      large content
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```